# Minimal value for xprv

Tags: private-key

If we have "smallest" (all characters minimal ASCII) pub address `1111111111111111111114oLvT2` which does not work in the network,

and smallest pub address `111111111111111111112BEH2ro` which does work,

what would be the "smallest" `xprv` key for Bitcoin mainnet that will work?

Comment: What do you mean by "minimal ASCII". Wouldn't that be ASCII character 0x00 "NULL"? Wouldn't the minimal printable ASCII character be 0x20 "SPACE" and the minimal ASCII digit be 0x30 "0"?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick yes, that's what I mean. In this case seems like the minimal will be `1`.